# move_base_flex loading DWB_local_planner using Adapter, but cannot plan

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, local-planner, smach, nav-core

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,  I'm trying to get familiar with SMACH and adapting [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/move_base_flex/Tutorials/SimpleSmachForMoveBaseFlex), but changing default dwa_local_planner to DWB, since it showed a great performance.

Since It's nav_core, I'm using [nav_core_adapter](https://github.com/locusrobotics/robot_navigation/tree/master/nav_core_adapter), loading DWB_local_planner as:

```
controllers:
  - name: 'BaseLocalPlanner'
    type: 'nav_core_adapter::LocalPlannerAdapter'
```

```
LocalPlannerAdapter:
  planner_name: dwb_local_planner::DWBLocalPlanner
DWBLocalPlanner:
  update_frequency: 5.0
```

While running move_base_flex, all the things are loaded without errors, but when choosing a goal, I'm getting a lot of :

`[ERROR] []: computeVelocityCommands exception: No valid trajectories out of 0!`

Any clue what the reason could be?
Am I missing something in SMACH python file?

**[EDIT 1]:**

`planner_ns/evaluation` output is a good debugging tool, thanks **@David Lu**

Output this message:

`frame_id: "odom_combined"` 
`twists: []`  
`best_index: 0`   
`worst_index: 0`

I found [his thread](https://answers.ros.org/question/344430/error-controller_server-no-valid-trajectories-out-of-0/). If I got it right, planner is waiting for `/odom` topic, but by defalult it's publishing  `/odom_combined`.

Also, local and global planner parameter's `global map:` set to `map` in common_parameters.yaml, which needs to be set as `odom` for local_planner_params.yaml.
The last, pay attention to the velocity, as it's explained in the link.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/352740/move_base_flex-loading-dwb_local_planner-using-adapter,-but-cannot-plan/) by [artemiialessandrini](https://answers.ros.org/users/36583/artemiialessandrini/) on ROS Answers with karma: 69 on 2020-05-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [artemiialessandrini](https://answers.ros.org/users/36583/artemiialessandrini/) on 2020-05-20**:
GetPath.action, ExePath.action explained at [294278/custom-global-path/](https://answers.ros.org/question/294278/custom-global-path/)

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2020-05-20**:
Can you capture the output of `planner_ns/evaluation` in a bag and post it?

**Comment by [artemiialessandrini](https://answers.ros.org/users/36583/artemiialessandrini/) on 2020-05-21**:
I updated a thread, thanks again! @David Lu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See **[EDIT]** in the header

1. capture the output of `planner_ns/evaluation`
2. Follow [this thread](https://answers.ros.org/question/344430/error-controller_server-no-valid-trajectories-out-of-0/):

1. pay attention `odom`  to be set as global_frame in local_costmap_params.yaml
2. have `/odom` topic
3. have planner set using **nav_core_adapter** as explained in description [locusrobotics/robot_navigation/nav_core_adapter](https://github.com/locusrobotics/robot_navigation/tree/master/nav_core_adapter)

---

Originally posted by [artemiialessandrini](https://answers.ros.org/users/36583/artemiialessandrini/) with karma: 69 on 2020-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2020-06-05**:
Glad it worked out for you.